# Change type of a field in wordpress code

Tags: php, wordpress

I hope someone can help me.

In my wordpress theme, i have a timeline. When i edit my timeline, i have different field (as you can see in the code). In the code the field date has the "textfield" type. I want to change it into a "date" type. When i replace textfield by date there is no field displayed anymore and i don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
array(
    "type" => "textfield",
    "holder" => "div",
    "class" => "",
    "heading" => __("Date", EWF_SETUP_THEME_DOMAIN),
    "param_name" => "date",
    "value" => 2000,
    "description" => __("Date of the timeline item", EWF_SETUP_THEME_DOMAIN)
),
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think value should be in date format .. say 06/05/2014 or 06-05-2015

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already try to change the value or to remove it from the array but there is still no field displayed

Comment: How about with date() , Have you tried that too ?

Comment: there is still nothing